# Apply an openlayers filter and have it persist when I save the map as an image

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have made an openlayers map with various polylines on it. I am using the default openstreetmap layer, but would like to darken it to make my polylines stand out. I've discovered that I can do this as follows:

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].on('postcompose', function (evt) {
   evt.context.canvas.style.filter="invert(99%)";
});
```

However, I'd also like to give my users the ability to download this map as a PNG. For that, I am using the following code, triggered from a button click:

```
map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
   var canvas = event.context.canvas;
   if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'mymap.png');
   } else {
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
         saveAs(blob, 'mymap.png')
      });
   }
});
map.renderSync();
```

Unfortunately, this does not preserve the amendment I made to adjust the canvas.

Please can someone help me? Thank you for reading.

Comment: just apply the same filter before you save the canvas

Comment: I have tried adding `canvas.style.filter="invert(99%)";` after defining `canvas` in my save code - but it has no impact.

Comment: Setting a style on a canvas element will not affect the output of `toBlob()` or `toDataURL()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a style filter on an element will not affect the output of `toBlob()` or `toDataURL()`.  If you want to change the canvas context instead of how the browser renders the canvas you will need a globalCompositeOperation (from the code you are using I presume you are using OpenLayers 5):

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].on('postcompose', function (evt) {
  evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'difference';
  evt.context.fillStyle = 'white';
  evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
  evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
```